# Include logging in docstring?

Tags: python, logging, docstring

I am writing my python functions according to the Google Python Style [guide](http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html) and I was wondering if I should include logging or print statements in the docstring? The logger is initiated in a previous statement.

```
def foo(bar):
    """ This function will foo the .. out of bar

    Args:
        bar (string) : bar

    Returns:
       fooed_bar (string) : bla bla
    """

    fooed_bar = bar + "blabla"
    logger.debug(bar)    
    return fooed_bar
```

Comment: Whether you should including logging how? Some statement in the docstring that says "this function will log 'bar'"? What good would that do?

Answer (score 3):

- It doesn't add any useful information about what the function does, but clutters up the docstring.
- It does not influence how the function is called or what value it returns, i.e. it is irrelevant to the API.
- It requires you to keep the function body in sync with the docstring, and especially what you're logging can frequently change during debugging, so it's almost guaranteed that the docstring and the actual code will diverge.

  - More meta: you should document *what and why*, not *how*.

The only time you should mention anything about logging is if it's relevant somehow, e.g.:

> `Note: when the logging level is set to 'debug', this function may produce a ginormous amount of logging data; beware.`

Other than that it seems entirely superfluous.